# Unable to display contents of array in a file

Tags: c, file

First, I am doing the following to display random and unique numbers on my console and in a specific file:

```
        for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            printf("unique random number is %d\n", array[y]);
            fprintf(fp, "unique random number is %d\n", array[y]);
```

Next I am using the following code to display the contents of an array holding a binary representation for the numbers generated earlier.

```
for (loop1 = loop; loop1 > -1; loop1--)
                printf("%d", arr[loop1]);
                printf("\n");
```

I am then using: `fprintf(fp, "%d", arr[loop1]);` to print these inside a file of my choice.

What am I doing wrong in my last piece of the code as the binary representation is not being printed out? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT: **

```
for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            printf("unique random number is %d\n", array[y]);
            fprintf(fp, "unique random number is %d\n", array[y]);
            value = array[y];

            for (loop = 0; loop < 1000; loop++)
            {
                if (value <= 1) { arr[loop] = 1; break; }       //if value is 1 after dividing put 1 in array
                if (value % 2 == 0) arr[loop] = 0;
                else arr[loop] = 1;

                value = value / 2;
            }
            for (loop1 = loop; loop1 > -1; loop1--)
                printf("%d", arr[loop1]);
                printf("\n");
                fprintf(fp, "%d", arr[loop1]);                      
        }
```

Comment: The binary representation on my console is still being printed out well. Somehow it is effecting what is written in the file.

Comment: I notice that there is no `{` for the second `for` loop. Do you have a separate loop for printing `arr[loop1]`?

Comment: No, I am printing `arr[loop1]` to my console using that code. I wish to then display this inside a file which I am writing to. I will post a wider range of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet of code is not correct:

```
        for (loop1 = loop; loop1 > -1; loop1--)
            printf("%d", arr[loop1]);
            printf("\n");
            fprintf(fp, "%d", arr[loop1]);
```

Notice the absense of a block `{ }`? This means that the `for` loop only includes the first statement. The code is equivalent to this:

```
        for (loop1 = loop; loop1 > -1; loop1--) {
            printf("%d", arr[loop1]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        fprintf(fp, "%d", arr[loop1]);
```

That means that you print `arr[-1]` to the file (=undefined behaviour!!!).

To print the same thing to file and stdout you probably want this:

```
        for (loop1 = loop; loop1 > -1; loop1--) {
            printf("%d", arr[loop1]);
            fprintf(fp, "%d", arr[loop1]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing to an file, the files are fully buffered. So, you have to flush the buffer after writing. Change your code for writing to an file like below.

```
for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    printf("unique random number is %d\n", array[y]);
    fprintf(fp, "unique random number is %d\n", array[y]);
    fflush(fp);
}
```

Once the buffer is flushed then only it will write the contents to an file.

I hope it will solve your problem